# How to read the saved extent of the QgsProject?

Tags: pyqgis, extents, qgs

I am trying to access the extent of QgsProject. How can i do that with PyQGIS?

Comment: Are you wanting to access the extent while the map is opened or closed?

Comment: I opened and loaded the project with read(QFileInfo(path)) method. QGIS automatically sets the extent to the last saved extend. I am trying get the values of the extent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for current extent:

```
bBox = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().extent()
```

Comment: I need to access it with QgsProject object

Answer (score 1):

To access the project extent with `QgsProject` object, outside QGIS, you also need to call the canva's `extent()` method. But you don't have immediately access to it, as you do in QGIS Python console.

You have to do:

```py
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
# Load providers
qgs.initQgis()

project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(root, canvas)
project.read(yourprojectpath)

# now you can get the extent
print(canvas.extent())

# or...
e = canvas.extent()
print(e.xMaximum())
print(e.yMaximum())
print(e.xMinimum())
print(e.yMinimum())
```

As pointed in [QGIS 3.x documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadproject.html), before loading the project, you have to to instantiate a `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` in order to synchronise the loaded project with the canvas. Then you can use the `canvas` object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to access it directly but you can read the `.qgs` project as a text file, search for `<extent>` and print the next 4 lines:

```
myfile = open('path/to/project_file', "r")
for line in myfile:
    if '<extent>' in line:
        for index in range(4):
            extent = myfile.next()
            print (extent).replace('\n', ' ')
```

[image: Project extent]